# Flux emit elements based on date time property

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

I've a scenario where I want to process events based on date time property in the event.

My failed attempt so far:

```java
class Data {
    private Integer id;
    private LocalDateTime sendAt;
}

List<Data> data = Arrays.asList(
        new Data(1, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(1)),
        new Data(2, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(2)),
        new Data(3, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(3)),
        new Data(4, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(5)),
        new Data(5, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(8)),
        new Data(6, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(13)),
        new Data(7, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(21)),
        new Data(8, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(34)),
        new Data(9, LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(55)));

Flux<Data> dataFlux = Flux.fromIterable(data);

dataFlux.takeWhile(d -> d.sendAt.isAfter( LocalDateTime.now() ))
        .subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

I'm expecting the events to be printed after `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...` seconds each.

Is this possible with Spring WebFlux / Reactor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible via combining `delayUntil` with `Mono.delay(<custom_time>)` & HTTP streaming with `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE` or SSE's `MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE`:

```java
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class FluxDateTime {
    @GetMapping(value = "/time", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Data> getData() {
        List<Data> data = Arrays.asList(
                new Data(1, 1),
                new Data(2, 2),
                new Data(3, 3),
                new Data(4, 5),
                new Data(5, 8),
                new Data(6, 13),
                new Data(7, 21),
                new Data(8, 34),
                new Data(9, 55));

        return Flux.fromIterable(data)
                .delayUntil(d -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(d.getDelay())));
    }

    /* Keep in mind that empty constructor, getters/setters
       are purely only for JSON serialization */
    private final class Data {
        private int id;
        private int delay;

        public Data() {}

        public Data(int id, int delay) {
            this.id = id;
            this.delay = delay;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getDelay() {
            return delay;
        }

        public void setDelay(int delay) {
            this.delay = delay;
        }
    }
}
```

Flux collection delays on each element until underlying Mono stream terminates. Each of the Monos are delayed with respective time in seconds based on input stream data.

In effect we have got streamed HTTP response with your desired custom delays:

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:8080/time
{"id":1,"delay":1} # after 1 sec
{"id":2,"delay":2} # after 2 sec
{"id":3,"delay":3} # and so on
{"id":4,"delay":5}
{"id":5,"delay":8}
{"id":6,"delay":13}
{"id":7,"delay":21}
{"id":8,"delay":34}
{"id":9,"delay":55}
```

Comment: Thanks @Xarvalus. I've modified your answer to, dataFlux.delayUntil(d -> Mono.delay(Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), d.sendAt))).subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x))